# Microsoft Pubcenter Ads In WPF Application

Tags: wpf, ads, wpf-4.0

Is there anyway to insert the MS Pubcenter Ads into a WPF 4.0 C# application. If so, please show me step by step how.

Comment: looking for an answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pubcenter does not support ads within anything other than WP7 or Win8 apps. Hopefully this will change to include standard desktop apps as we have a moderately successful game on WP7 that I would like to integrate ad support for and release on the desktop, but for now we'll need to look elsewhere for desktop ad revenue. I haven't found a solution yet either, unfortunately, so if anyone has a suggestion I'd like to hear it too.